# spark sql error while querying sql server table

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

Error while trying to query sql server table please help.

Specifying database name or other qualifiers are not allowed for temporary tables. If the table name has dots (.) in it, please quote the table name with backticks (`).;

```html
  val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
      val querytest=sqlContext.sql(query)
      val prop=new Properties()
      val url2="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;user=admin;password=oracle;database=AdventureWorks2014"
      prop.setProperty("user","admin")
      prop.setProperty("password","oracle")
      val test=sqlContext.read.jdbc(url2,"Customer",prop)
```

Made changes to the code which worked:-

```html
package com.kali.db

/**
 * Created by kalit_000 on 06/12/2015.
 */

import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.{JdbcRDD, RDD}
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

case class SparkSqlValueClassMPP(driver:String,url:String,username:String,password:String,table:String,opdelimeter:String,lowerbound:String,upperbound:String,numberofparitions:String,parallelizecolumn:String)

object SparkDBExtractorMPP {

  def main (args: Array[String]) {

    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.WARN)
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.WARN)

    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("SparkDBExtractorMPP").set("spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs", "false")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    def opfile(value:DataFrame,delimeter:String):RDD[String]=
    {
      value.map(x => x.toString.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace(",",delimeter))
    }

    //read the application context file
    val ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("sparkDBExtractorMpp.xml")
    val DBinfo = ctx.getBean("SparkSQLDBExtractorMPP").asInstanceOf[SparkSqlValueClassMPP]

    val driver = DBinfo.driver
    val url = DBinfo.url
    val username = DBinfo.username
    val password = DBinfo.password
    val table = DBinfo.table
    val opdelimeter=DBinfo.opdelimeter
    val lowerbound=DBinfo.lowerbound.toInt
    val upperbound=DBinfo.upperbound.toInt
    val numberofpartitions=DBinfo.numberofparitions.toInt
    val parallelizecolumn=DBinfo.parallelizecolumn


    println("DB Driver:-%s".format(driver))
    println("DB Url:-%s".format(url))
    println("Username:-%s".format(username))
    println("Password:-%s".format(password))
    println("Table:-%s".format(table))
    println("Opdelimeter:-%s".format(opdelimeter))
    println("Lowerbound:-%s".format(lowerbound))
    println("Upperbound:-%s".format(upperbound))
    println("Numberofpartitions:-%s".format(numberofpartitions))
    println("Parallelizecolumn:-%s".format(parallelizecolumn))

    try {
    val props=new Properties()
    props.put("user",username)
    props.put("password",password)
    props.put("driver",driver)

    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    val df = sqlContext.read.jdbc(url,table,parallelizecolumn,lowerbound,upperbound,numberofpartitions,props)

    df.show(10)

    opfile(df,opdelimeter).saveAsTextFile("C:\\Users\\kalit_000\\Desktop\\typesafe\\scaladbop\\op.txt")

    } catch {
      case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace
    }
    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

I am using Spring bean to make spark code configurable

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
        "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
    <bean id="queryProps" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    </bean>

    <bean id="SparkSQLDBExtractorMPP" class="com.kali.db.SparkSqlValueClassMPP">
        <constructor-arg value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <constructor-arg value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;user=admin;password=oracle;database=AdventureWorks2014" />
        <constructor-arg value="admin" />
        <constructor-arg value="oracle" />
        <constructor-arg value="(select top 100 CustomerID,StoreID,TerritoryID,AccountNumber,ModifiedDate from customer ) as customer" />
        <constructor-arg value="~" />
        <constructor-arg value="1" />
        <constructor-arg value="100" />
        <constructor-arg value="8" />
        <constructor-arg value="CustomerID" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use spark 1.4 the function load is depreciated.

> `load
>   public DataFrame load(String path,
>                String source)`
>   **Deprecated.** As of 1.4.0, replaced by `read().format(source).load(path)`.
>   Returns the dataset stored at path as a DataFrame, using the given data  source.
>   Parameters:
>   path - (undocumented)
>   source - (undocumented)
>   Returns:
>   (undocumented)

The new way to do it is here http://www.sparkexpert.com/2015/01/02/load-database-data-into-spark-using-jdbcrdd-in-java/

Comment: I don't want column names to be hard coded while getting data out of result set is there other way , I want my code to be reusable by passing values (db,url,username,password,query) to spring framework, my code should connect to any database and dump data out to a file I tried JdbcRDD only issue we need to mention column names at r.getString(1) which I don't want to , val myRDD = new JdbcRDD(sc, () =>
          DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password), query + " where ? = ? ", 1, 1, 1,
          r => r.getString(1)+","+r.getString(2)+","+r.getString(3))

Comment: I'm not sure if I get you wrong or not . however I think you can just pass variable for column names .  Or you can load all table to dataframe by select * then do your query using dataframe select is more flexible and faster.

Comment: can I write plain sql on df ? val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc) val df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map("url" -> url,"dbtable" -> "customer","query"-> query,"driver" -> driver)).load()

Comment: Yes , you can do it. Just check apache spark dataframe to your corresponding version . the syntax is changed between different versions.

Comment: Can you accept the answer if this helps you please thanks

Comment: below worked ok ,  val df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map("url" -> url,"dbtable" -> table,"driver" -> driver)).load()
     df.registerTempTable(table)
     val OP=sqlContext.sql(query)

     opfile(OP,opdelimeter).saveAsTextFile("C:\\Users\\kalit_000\\Desktop\\typesafe\\scaladbop\\op.txt")

Comment: thanks zt1983811 for your help , I created a reusable component lets name this as DB extractor ...